# initialize during declaration and create shorthand getter/setter

Tags: c#, setter, getter

How do I initialize the member variables during declaration and create the getter/setter shorthand? Is it possible or do I have to use the constructor to assign the value?

For example I want to do something similarl to this

```
public class Money
{
   public int dollars = 200 {get; set;}
}
```

or

```
public int dollars = 200;

dollars 
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In C# 6 and later, you can initialize auto-implemented properties similarly to fields:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; } = "Jane";
```

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Either

```
public class Money
{
    private int dollars = 200;
    public int Dollars
    {
        get { return dollars; }
        set { dollars = value; }
    }
}
```

or

```
public class Money
{
    public int Dollars { get; set; }

    public Money() 
    {
        Dollars = 200;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there is currently no way to achieve this.

You must either assign the default value when you declare the properties *backing field* or assign the default value from the constructor if you are using an automatic property.

Comment: you're talking pre C#6  I see others have given an example.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Money
{
  public int Dollars {get;set;}

  public Money()
  {
    Dollars = 200;
  }
}
```